# Errors reported from livepatch

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Today `livepatch` got updated automatically and right after the update, the following errors started appearing in the journal log.

```
4/5/23 7:12 PM  canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd    Client information is recent, not refreshing.
4/5/23 7:12 PM  canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd    SRU date retrieval failed
4/5/23 7:12 PM  canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd    failed to store the kernel SRU date: parsing time "" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "" as "2006"
4/5/23 7:12 PM  systemd Started snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.32b5d92e-4ddd-46b2-a77c-bf91e9286b65.scope.
4/5/23 7:12 PM  canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd    SRU date retrieval failed
4/5/23 7:12 PM  systemd Started snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.e6c3ed24-390f-414d-8426-8568a6c20a46.scope.
4/5/23 7:12 PM  canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd    SRU date retrieval failed
4/5/23 7:12 PM  systemd Started snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.f1e31d92-7d61-4e97-a96b-ebb61d59e24c.scope.
4/5/23 7:12 PM  canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd    SRU date retrieval failed
4/5/23 7:12 PM  systemd Started snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch.8776a5a0-76af-40b6-867f-24fca13195c4.scope.
4/5/23 7:12 PM  canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd    SRU date retrieval failed
```

Do you know anything about this?
Thank you.

**Update:**

The latest `canonical-livepatch version 10.5.4 revision 202` corrects the errors. The issue doesn't seem to exist any more.

Comment: We are seeing the same thing. I think this is a bad update. Not sure what to do about it at the moment though as I think we ultimately need to wait for a patch :-/

Comment: As a workaround you can roll back to the previous snap on the system. List the installed snaps with `snap list canonical-livepatch --all` and then roll back with `sudo snap revert canonical-livepatch --revision 164`.

Comment: @Dogsbody, Yes, it's definitely a bad update. The errors appear on a second computer too here now. I don't know if we have to revert to the old revision though. I think that despite the date error, it otherwise works. I can't be sure though, yet.

Comment: There's [a bug report about this on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/2015734).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [@Dogsbody](https://askubuntu.com/users/185044/dogsbody) for [their comment with a workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462438/errors-reported-from-livepatch/1462701#comment2560344_1462438):

> As a workaround you can roll back to the previous snap on the system. List the installed snaps with `snap list canonical-livepatch --all` and then roll back with `sudo snap revert canonical-livepatch --revision`